# How do i use net user inside a C# console program?

Tags: c#

I can't seem to get it to work, the only thing that happens is a CMD prompt pops up saying how to use the net function, if you could help me please, i would be grateful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Enable_Elevated_Admin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Enable Admin";
            Process enable_admin = new Process();
            Process disable_admin = new Process();
            enable_admin.StartInfo.Arguments = "user " + "administrator" + "/active:yes";
            enable_admin.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\net";
            disable_admin.StartInfo.Arguments = "user " + "administrator" + "/active:no";
            disable_admin.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\net";
            ConsoleKeyInfo i;
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to ClassyJakey's C# project for enabling the elevated admin easily.");
            Console.WriteLine("Options :");
            Console.WriteLine("1) Enable elevated admin");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Disable elevated admin");
            i = Console.ReadKey();

            if (i.KeyChar.ToString() == "1")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enabling admin, please wait!");
                enable_admin.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Enabled!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine("Creating log...");
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\log.txt");
                writer.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today);
                writer.WriteLine("Enable Admin Log - By ClassyJakey");
                writer.WriteLine("Enabling admin was successful!");
                writer.WriteLine("If you have errors, please contact classyjakey.");
                writer.Close();
            }

            if (i.KeyChar.ToString() == "2")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Disabling admin, please wait!");
                disable_admin.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Disabled!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                StreamWriter writer2 = new StreamWriter("c:\\log2.txt");
                writer2.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today);
                writer2.WriteLine("Enable Admin Log - By ClassyJakey");
                writer2.WriteLine("Disabling! admin was successful!");
                writer2.WriteLine("If you have errors, please contact classyjakey.");
                writer2.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You thought you would find a easter egg by not putting 1 or 2?");
                Console.WriteLine("Well, your right.");
                Console.WriteLine("+      o     +              o    ");
                Console.WriteLine("    +             o     +       +");
                Console.WriteLine("o          +                     ");
                Console.WriteLine("    o  +           +        +    ");
                Console.WriteLine("+        o     o       +        o");
                Console.WriteLine("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_,------,      o    ");
                Console.WriteLine(@"_-_-_-_-_-_-_-|   /\_/\ meow    ");
                Console.WriteLine("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_|__( ^ w^)  +     +");
                Console.WriteLine(@"_-_-_-_-_-_-_-   ""  ""          ");
                Console.WriteLine("+      o         o   +       o   ");
                Console.WriteLine("    +         +                  ");
                Console.WriteLine("o        o         o      o     +");
                Console.WriteLine("    o           +                ");
                Console.WriteLine("+      +     o        o      +   ");
                StreamWriter writer3 = new StreamWriter("c:\\log3.txt");
                writer3.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Today);
                writer3.WriteLine("+      o     +              o    ");
                writer3.WriteLine("    +             o     +       +");
                writer3.WriteLine("o          +                     ");
                writer3.WriteLine("    o  +           +        +    ");
                writer3.WriteLine("+        o     o       +        o");
                writer3.WriteLine("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_,------,      o    ");
                writer3.WriteLine(@"_-_-_-_-_-_-_-|   /\_/\ meow    ");
                writer3.WriteLine("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_|__( ^ w^)  +     +");
                writer3.WriteLine(@"_-_-_-_-_-_-_-   ""  ""          ");
                writer3.WriteLine("+      o         o   +       o   ");
                writer3.WriteLine("    +         +                  ");
                writer3.WriteLine("o        o         o      o     +");
                writer3.WriteLine("    o           +                ");
                writer3.WriteLine("+      +     o        o      +   ");
                writer3.Close();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't read the question fully, but I just want to mention that "administrator" + "/active:yes" will result in "administrator/active:yes". This might not have the expected result.

Comment: I see that you will get nyancats even if you choose option 1...

Comment: The 2nd nyancat is to write it to a log file.

Comment: You could probably make it a constant and call it twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're missing a space to separate the arguments:

```
    enable_admin.StartInfo.Arguments = "user " + "administrator " + "/active:yes";
                                                               ^----
    enable_admin.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\net";
    disable_admin.StartInfo.Arguments = "user " + "administrator " + "/active:no";
                                                                ^----
    disable_admin.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\net";
```